# Why won't a certain object combine into another in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, icon

I am making an icon pack using Inkscape that is focused around brand and social icons. I am planning on adding the FreeBSD logo to the pack, so I have been recreating the logo:

[image]

However, when I try to combine paths and set the color to black, this appears:

[image]

As you can see, instead of it having no color like the other objects, the right ear turns completely black. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the direction of one of the paths before you attempt combining them, using `Path` > `Reverse`. Or if you have already done it, you can select the path with the Edit Paths by Node tool, and just reverse it.

Here's an example showing two circles combined. The one on left has both paths in the same direction, the one on the right, has the centre path reversed.

[image: Example of Combined paths]

Another way to do this is make sure the path to cut out is on top, and use `Path` > `Difference` instead. That way you don't have to worry about path direction. The result will be a combined shape.